# Display number in brackets using toLocaleString for negative values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecma

I have been trying to change the numbers in AngularJS application according to the countries and used `.toLocaleString` function over entire application using below function

```
numberValueTransformation(value) {
    if (value === 0 || value === undefined) {
      return 0;
    }
    const currencyLocale = this.UserPreferences.getCountryLocale().replace(/fr-FR/g, 'de-DE');
    const currencyCode = this.UserPreferences.getCountryCode();
    return Number(value).toLocaleString(currencyLocale, {
      // style: 'currency',
      currency: currencyCode,
      minimumFractionDigits: 2
    });
}
```

The above function works perfectly fine but I have a requirement to show the negative values in brackets over whole application. Can we modify `.toLocaleString` to get the negative values in brackets or do I need to change in the entire application manually?
I get the value as $123456689. But if a negative value i get -$123456789, but here i want the value as ($123456789) <--- brackets represents minus.

Comment: What means *"the negative values in brackets"*?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I think he means parentheses; i.e., "(100)" means -100.

Comment: yes i mean the same !

Comment: There is no built-in method for these. See [How can I format numbers as dollars currency string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/149055/215552) for some attempts.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when and why would one want to put a negative number into a string, positive and inside brackets?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan. I needed to change currency values to their particular formats, such as if user wants euro format, then it should display the number like this 12.34.56,78 instead of USA format 12,34,56.78 and i think this way of doing in just the front end of the app is abolutely fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of directly returning the result, you can wire up the check yourself. Do the conversion on a positive number, if instead the original value is less then 0 then wrap in brackets.:

```
var absValue = Math.abs(value);
var returnString = Number(absValue).toLocaleString(currencyLocale, {
    // style: 'currency',
    currency: currencyCode,
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
});

return value < 0 ? '(' + returnString + ')' : returnString;
```

Comment: This worked very closer as i needed but  i need a display where minus sign is outside the brackets. For eg ** -(123.233.42,99) **

Comment: Updated my answer... just return the - in front.

Comment: For negative accounting numbers, the parentheses already signal a negative value. The minus sign is redundant.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.toLocaleString` function directly as follows:

```
function numberValueTransformation(value) {

    if (value === null || value === undefined) {
      return 'some special value like N/A';
    }

    const currencyLocale = this.UserPreferences.getCountryLocale().replace(/fr-FR/g, 'de-DE');
    const currencyCode = this.UserPreferences.getCountryCode();

    return Number(value).toLocaleString(currencyLocale, {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: currencyCode,
      currencySign: 'accounting', // this is the key
      minimumFractionDigits: 2
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this maybe look at the numbro.js library https://numbrojs.com/ There is a feature to format negative values in brackets as requested. The code would work like this

```js
console.log(
numbro(-123456.78).formatCurrency({
    thousandSeparated: true,
    mantissa: 2,
    negative: "parenthesis" // This does what you want
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/numbro@2.3.1/dist/numbro.min.js"></script>
```

There are lots of other formatting options too see https://numbrojs.com/format.html#currency